# Creating a histogram with appropriate counts and labels in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataset (dat), which I am hard-coding in here:

```
dat = c(5, 9, 5, 6, 5, 6, 8, 4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 7, 4, 1, 4, 6, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7, 6)
table(dat)
```

By doing the table function above on the data, I see that there should be a count of 1 for values of 1, and count of 1 for values of 2. However, when I plot the data using hist, I get a count of 2.

```
hist(dat, col="lightgreen", labels = TRUE, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,27))
```

This is the first problem. The other problem is that I am trying to plot the x label value for the corresponding bin (where there should be 11 bins, labeled 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10). Even though I have no 0 values or 10 values, I would like to illustrate that they had a count of 0, and have their bins - like the rest- labeled. How can I accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are describing is not a histogram, but a bar chart. Histograms are for continusous random variables to estimate the underlying density function. If you just want count of observations, use `barplot(table(dat))`

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you! But I thought bar charts were for categorical variables, and histograms were for quantitative variables. Since the variable is quantitative (with numeric values between 0 and 10), then I thought I should use a histogram. Even though the "bins" are equal to simply one value, and not a range of values. But I am not sure, I will look into it!

Comment: There are two types of quantitative random variables: continuous and discrete. Different rules apply to each and histograms were designed for the former and you seem to have described a situation more like the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
am = hist(dat, col="lightgreen", labels = TRUE, 
     breaks=seq(min(dat)-2,max(dat)),
     axes=F)
axis(2)
axis(1,at=am$mids,seq(min(dat)-1,max(dat)))
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I want. The only thing I would want to also do is indicate a count of zero for values 0 and 10. (Right now, it only goes to values 1 and 9 both having a count of 1).

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean like this:

```
hist(dat, col="lightgreen", labels = TRUE, 
  xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,27), breaks = 0:10, at=0:10)
```

Comment: Yes thank you. But, I also wanted to put all of the x labels (of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) directly under their bins. Currently, I only have the x labels (0,2,4,6,8,10). Also, their is no bin indicating a count of zero for the value zero.